# Rails 5 Why I always get default date in initialize method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have class that get articles and two dates. My initialize method in class looks like that:

```
def initialize(articles:, date1: nil, date2: nil)
    @articles = articles
    @date1 ||= DEFAULT_DATE1
    @date2 ||= DEFAULT_DATE2
end
```

I don't know why my @date1 and @date2 has DEFAULT_DATE value even if I send parameters like that:

```
Example.new(articles: articles, date1: '2021-10-10', date2: '2021-10-11')
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be checking for the params you receive and then assign accordingly.

Changing the code to this will work

```
def initialize(articles:, date1: nil, date2: nil)
  @articles = articles
  @date1 = date1 || DEFAULT_DATE1
  @date2 = date2 || DEFAULT_DATE2
end
```

**The Issue and explanation:**

When you do this

```
@date1 ||= DEFAULT_DATE1
```

It's checking if `@date1` has any value (which it does not) so you get `DEFAULT_DATE1` assigned to the `@date1`

Answer (score 0):

> Where is the problem?

You never use the arguments `date1` and `date2`. You probably want to assign them to their respective instance variables.

Unless you have very specific needs, it's easier to move the defaults right into the argument definition:

```
def initialize(articles:, date1: DEFAULT_DATE1, date2: DEFAULT_DATE2)
  @articles = articles
  @date1 = date1
  @date2 = date2
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but if I will create object like that - `Example.new(articles: articles, date1: nil, date2: nil)` then `@date1` and `@date2` will have nil not default. Am I wrong?

Comment: That's correct, they will be `nil`. IMO, that behavior is more correct because your explicitly passing `nil` (as opposed to omitting the argument)

Comment: Ye, but I want set default dates even if date1 is nil. But thanks! :)